# How to have table cell as long as possible, but smaller than max-width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a dynamic table, and I would like to make the width of the first cell of each row responsive to the size of its content.
For now, the text of the cell breaks randomly, depending on the data.

What I would like, is to have the cell be as long as it needs until some max-width, where it would actually break.

So for example, if the max-width is 200px:
If the largest cell of a column takes 100px, the column would be 100px.
If it was 30px, the column would be 30px.
But if it was 300px, the column would be 200px, and the cells over 300pm would line-break.

I have tried setting min-width and max-width, but then the content has the minimum width and does not expand as needed up to 200px.

Comment: Kindly provide your code. Thanks

Comment: The table code is generated with pandas, i don't have access to it, and I am not sure it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the contents of the cell inside an element with `max-width`:

```css
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.contents {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div class="contents">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="cell">
  <div class="contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ligula lorem, efficitur sit amet massa consectetur, gravida venenatis dui.
  </div>
</div>
```

Better don't set `max-width` directly on the cell because ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths))

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of `min-width` and `max-width` on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is
>   undefined.

Comment: I don't have access to the html generation.. Pandas manages it. The only way I found is to set max width, whitespace no wrap, and text-overflow ellipsis.

Comment: What I would like is to have something like whitespace no wrap and then at max width, it wraps :)

Comment: @Codemon CSS Tables L3 will allow `max-width` on table cells but it seems nobody has implemented that early draft. If you can't change the HTML, screw the tables by displaying them as flexboxes or some other layout.